# What is my Connection String Visual studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

I made a database using the sql server db feature in VS-2015 and am trying to nest 2 grid views. I have everything set up as wished until I get to the connection string part. I have to place the connection string in my aspx page and in my aspx.cs page. I just don't know where to find the connection string of my db located in server explorer or if there is a different way to do it because it is already in the project file

*PROPER CONNECTION STRING IN PLACE ERROR*

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
 {
  GridView gv = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("GridView2");
  SqlDataSource dbSrc = new SqlDataSource();
  dbSrc.ConnectionString =    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\HUTDMS.mdf;Integrated Security=True"].ConnectionString;
  dbSrc.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM textBooks WHERE thirteenISBN = '" + GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value + "' ORDER BY BookTitle";
  gv.DataSource = dbSrc;
  gv.DataBind();
 }
}
```

In my connection string I'm receiving an underline in every '\' in my connection string saying "unrecognized escape sequence" how do I negate this and use my connection string?

[image]

Comment: Try using a verbatim string by putting @ before your connection string `[@"Data Source..."]`

Comment: That takes care of my syntax error but now that everything seems to be right, when I test it, I receive The connection name 'ConnectionName' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` correctly.Your connection string should be stored in the web.config file under the `<connectionStrings>` element:

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=HUTDMS;Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;"/>
```

And the `name` property that you specified in the `web.config` file should be used as the key when using `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

So the complete logic to bind the books data to the GridView could potentially look something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        var ds = new SqlDataSource();
        ds.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        ds.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM textBooks ORDER BY BookTitle";
        gv.DataSource = ds;
        gv.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**Output in the browser:**

[image: Bind GridView control to SqlDataSource]

Answer (score 0):

You need replace |DataDirectory| to your Physical folder path like 'C:\app\myDb.mdf'

Comment: would I have to do that in my web.config file as well then because thats where |datadirectory| is coming from